# Как поменять местами элементы списка?

Tags: c#

Как поменять 2 элемента одного списка местами без помощи дополнительных переменных?

Например: `а[1]` и `a[2]`, где `а[1]`(имеет значение 10) и `a[2]`(имеет значение 20).
Мне нужно поменять их местами, чтобы на `а[1]` (было 20), а на `a[2]`(было 10).

Comment: у списков есть метод sort()
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/b0zbh7b6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: А зачем вам это? Понятности коду явно не добавится. Эффективности тоже (компилятор достаточно умный). Может пригодиться разве что на собеседовании в плохую компанию.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Без дополнительных переменных не получится. Нужно же где-то хранить значение.

Пример:

```
a[1] = 10;
a[2] = 20;

var temp = a[1];
a[1] = a[2];
a[2] = temp;
```

Либо же добавлять этот элемент в конец списка, менять значение и удалять элемент с конца списка. Но этот вариант более сложный и менее адекватный.

Comment: помню на питоне занимался там есть двойное присваивание или как то по другому называется, где можно одновременно присваивать, пример:  а = с и сразу же с= а( я не помню как точно там пишется но суть в том что эти переменные как бы менялись значениями), ну и код там выходил в 3 строки... жаль что тут так нельзя я думал шарп поновороченней и возможностей побольше(

Comment: @kross так в чем проблема, определите метод swap(x,y) и радуйтесь. Обмен значениями всегда происходит через доп. переменную, даже если это от вас спрятали за функцию или оператор. Так что в питоне наоборот хуже сделали, код то короче, но понимания что за кадром нет.

Answer (score 3):

Для целых чисел:

```
int x = 10, y = 20;

y ^= x ^= y;
x ^= y;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  x = x + y;  
  y = x - y;  
  x = x - y;
```

или

```
  x = x * y;  
  y = x / y;  
  x = x / y;
```

Comment: А если вместо int используется string? Городить огород с string.Replace?)

Comment: сделайте пометку что это только для целых типов. с дробными и не числами работать не будет. во всяком случае в чистом виде